# Best resource to verify weak cipher suites

Tags: tls, ciphers

Many tools enable to list accepted ciphers but not all of them verify if these ciphers are secure.
For example, Nmap with script ssl-enum-ciphers ranks some ciphers as secure even though actually this ciphers are not recommended anymore (for example do not support PFS).

I often use https://ciphersuite.info/ to verify if listed ciphers are recommended but I am looking for other databases/services like this, where I can check if a particular cipher suite is still secure and/or recommended. Maybe a more "official" and regularly updated database?

Comment: For TLS I like specially https://testssl.sh/, not sure how frequent they update the code/data

Comment: There is no "official" source, because there is no "Office of TLS". Furthermore, product recommendations are off-topic here. Finally, the recommended testssl.sh is also my personal preference, so there you go

Comment: You can take the latest version of OpenSSL and then do a `openssl ciphers -V 'ALL:!HIGH'`. This gives you at least a view what the OpenSSL developers think.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: not really; the OpenSSL categories (EXPORT,LOW,MEDIUM,HIGH) are based solely on the symmetric keysize and don't consider keyexchange, auth, or mode at all, much less kx and auth _parameters_ which aren't in the ciphersuite. And since 1.1.0 in 2016 by default export, singleDES (obsolete), RC4 (bias), and tripleDES (sweet64) are not even built so they are never listed; they don't need to be excluded from (that) OpenSSL but might from other things. Also ALL does not list 'NULL' suites -- which are still built(!) but again often don't need to be excluded.